# Proving that $P\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} \right )\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i})$ by induction

Tags: probability, proof-verification, induction

**Proposition 1**: Let $A_{1},\dots, A_{n}$ be events in the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Then $$P\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} \right )\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i}).$$

Let's start with a lemma.

**Lemma 1**: Let $A$ and $B$ be events in $\mathcal{F}$. Then $P(A\cup B)\leq P(A)+P(B)$.

**(Fast) proof to Lemma 1**: Note that $A\cup B = (A\setminus (A\cap B))\cup B$ and $(A\setminus (A\cap B))\cap B= \emptyset$, then $$
P(A\cup B)=P(A\setminus (A\cap B))+P(B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B).
$$
Since $P(A\cap B)\geq 0$, we have $0\leq P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$. $\blacksquare $

**Proof to Proposition 1**:  Let $Q(n)$ denote the statement. We wish to prove it by induction that $Q(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 2$. The statement $Q(2)$ is clearly true, see Lemma 1. Assume now that $Q(k)$ is true for some $k\geq 2$. Let $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}$, and we see that
\begin{align*}
P\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_{i} \right )&=P(B\cup A_{k+1})\\
&\leq P(B)+P(A_{k+1})\tag{Lemma 1}\\
&= P\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i} \right )+P(A_{k+1})\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}P(A_{i})+P(A_{k+1})\tag{assumption}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}P(A_{i}),
\end{align*}
which shows that $Q(k+1)$ is true. Hence the statement $Q(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 2$. $\blacksquare $

**Question(s)**: I doubt if $n=1$ should have been shown too, since it's trivial. How is the proof so far?

Comment: This is correct (note that you also use the induction hypothesis in the fist inequality).

Comment: You're right that $n=1$ is trivial, and your inductive step applies when going from $n=1$ to $n=2$, so you just need to remark that it is trivial and you're fine. The rest of your proof is good.

Comment: @ClementC.It's possible (likely) the OP has proved the $n=2$ result elsewhere. You're right though, of course.

Comment: @ClementC. I didn't really use that induction hypothesis in the first inequality. I have edited the post, where I added a lemma to prove this inequality. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Thanks. I'll keep it in my mind. Do I have to prove it for the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ seperately, and then assuming that the statement is true for some $n\geq 2$? Or should I assume that the statement is true for some $n\geq 1$, if the case $n=1$ is shown to be true and not showing the case $n=2$?

Comment: Ok, $n=1$ is trivial, and $n=2$ is your initial lemma. The point is that you don't need your lemma, because you may assume the case $n=2$ as well in your inductive step (this is because you may assume the statement for all $n$ less than or equal to some particular $k$, rather than just for $n=k$).

Comment: In summary, if you assume the inductive hypothesis for some *particular* value of $n$, then you require your lemma. If you instead assume the inductive hypothesis for all $n$ less than or equal to some particular value, then you *don't* need your lemma, because you are assuming your lemma in the inductive step! This is called "strong induction" (if you haven't seen it before) and it's completely equivalent to "normal" induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as asked has been answered in the comments; I will use this space here to expand on a discussion about induction that developed there.

Suppose you want to prove some statement $P(n)$ for all natural $n$. *Proof by induction* is a proof technique by which we show $P(k)$ being true implies $P(k+1)$ is true, so if we can prove that $P$ is true for some natural number, it is true for all the naturals that follow it: $P(1)$ is true because we prove it, $P(2)$ is true because $P(1)$ implies it by the inductive step; $P(3)$ is true because $P(2)$ implies it, and so on.

However, sometimes it is hard to deduce $P(k+1)$ just by assuming $P(k)$. Well, can we use any other information? It turns out we can: we can use *all* the $P(n)$ back down to our base case! That is, if we can prove that assuming $P(k)$ *and the extra things* $P(1)$,$P(2)$,$P(3) \ldots P(k-1)$ implies $P(k+1)$, then we still get to deduce that the proposition is true by induction! This is called *Strong Induction*, because you it looks like you are making stronger assumptions than you are in *Weak* (normal) induction. It's not easy to prove that these two techniques are equivalent, you can find a proof easily online or you can just believe me.

So how is this relevant? Well in your proof you use the inductive step twice: once is the usual way, in your second to last line. But the lemma you proved at the beginning is *also* an example of the inductive hypothesis when $n=2$. It's completely fine to prove the $n=2$ case as a lemma and deduce the theorem by weak induction. Your proof is correct.

*However*, Clement and I were trying to point out that you don't have to do this anyway! Because you can use that technique of strong induction to assume *both* that $P(2)$ is true *and* $P(k)$ is true to deduce that $P(k+1)$ is true. That's all we were trying to explain.

Comment: I think I get it. It makes even more sense why the strong induction is called to be strong. I want to be sure if my words are correct to use for the proof; Assume that the statements from $Q(1)$ to $Q(k)$ are all true for some $k\geq 1$. [...]. If this is true, then I understand why the Lemma 1 shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yep, that's right! You could just say "Assume $Q(2)$ and $Q(k)$ for some $k > 1$". Again, it's not that lemma 1 *shouldn't* be used, it's absolutely correct - you just don't *need* it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, indicating that when you say probability space you mean the modern measure theoretic definition and not the elementary probability definition, I feel obligated to give a better approach.

There is no need to use induction. The definition of $P$ being a measure includes the fact that for $E_i$ a countable pairwise disjoint family
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(E_i).
$$
This is called **countable additivity** and it is the defining property of a measure.
Now consider $A_i$ that are not disjoint. Define $A_1' = A_1$ and recursively $A_i' := A_i\setminus \cup_{k=1}^{i-1}A_k$. Think $A_i'$ is the part of $A_i$ that hasn't been covered yet. Then the $A_i'$ are disjoint and $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i'$ so
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i'\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i') \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i).
$$
Where here we used the lemma that if $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$ because $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B$ so $P(A) = P(A\setminus B) + P(B) \geq P(B)$. Note that in order to get the result for a finite collection $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, simply define $A_{n+k}:= \emptyset$ for all $k>0$.